# Solving a system of ODE which may parametrize hyperbolas

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following system of ODE's
$$x'=a\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}$$
$$y'=a\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$$
for some constant $a$. The context where this shows up is rather intrincate and prefer not to talk about it because it wouldn't add anything to the discussion. However, I can say that I have reasons to believe that the solutions of this system may parametrize hyperbolas on the plane, yet I haven't found how to explicitly get the solution. I've actually tried some change of coordinates like $r^2=x^2+y^2$ and some other (probably) angular coordinate, yet, unsuccesfully. I would appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Whats wrong with dividing one equation by the other? $dy/dx = y'/x' = x/y$ implies that $y dy = x dx$ and so $y^2 = x^2 + C$.

Comment: Well that wouldn't give me the exact parametrization of the curve (I mean how fast we move along the curve depending on the velocity vector), would it???, but the bright side is that it does corroborates the suspicion on the solution being a hyperbola

Comment: For that you then observe that $(xy)'=x'y+xy'=a$, so that you get a quadratic system for $x,y$.

Comment: Yeah that should work, nice tricks  @Lutz Lehmann!!! Thank you guys.

Comment: Alternatively, you could just multiply the $x'$ ODE by $x$, the $y'$ ODE by $y$ and subtract the two to get $$0 = xx' - yy' = \frac{1}{2} (x^{2})' - \frac{1}{2}(y^{2})' = \frac{1}{2} (x^{2} - y^{2})' \implies \dots$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you complexify the problem by setting $z=x+iy$, you get
$$
z'=\frac{ia\bar z}{|z|^2}=\frac{ia}{z}\implies z^2=2iat+C
$$
where $C$ is now a complex number as integration constant.

Comment: This is more neat, and actually useful. Thanks @Lutz Lehmann